# Ставить ли запятую?

Tags: пунктуация, ссп

Подскажите, нужна ли запятая в предложении: Цитирование аналогичных статей не считается заметкой и в статье оно не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Катя, это же сложносочинённое предложение, повествовательное - конечно, запятая нужна.

Смотрите, у Вас две основы: **цитирование не считается** (заметкой) и **оно не нужно**:

*Цитирование аналогичных статей не считается заметкой, и в статье оно не нужно.*

Comment: Мне кажется, вы ошибаетесь. Чутье мне отчетливо говорит, что запятая здесь не нужна, хотя какое формальное правило тут подходит, сообразить трудно. Может быть, это: "Запятая перед союзами и, да (в значении «и»), или, либо не ставится, если соединяемые ими предложения имеют общий второстепенный член" ("в статье"). Например:
    По улицам двигались грузовики и мчались легковые машины.

Comment: Два подлежащих, два сказуемых, интонация повествовательная, общих  слов нет, - нормальное ССП. С запятой. В Вашем примере общее (отменяющее запятую) *по улицам*.

Answer (score 0):

Весьма странный смысл у высказывания. Что значит "цитирование не считается заметкой"? И что вообще есть "заметка". Неясность смысла позволяет давать различные интерпретации.

Если в первой части тоже имеется в виду "в статье" (а как иначе-то понимать?), то это "в статье" может претендовать на роль общего члена. Тогда запятая не нужна.

Вот чуть изменим: "*В статье цитирование аналогичных статей не считается заметкой и оно не нужно."*

Здесь отсутствие запятой вполне мотивировано, если "в статье" относится ко второму члену. Наш вариант несколько непривычен, "в статье" тут принадлежит формально ко второй части, но ведь в правилах нет никаких оговорок.

Так что хотелось бы прежде понять смысл. Мне, признаться, тоже не очень хочется ставить там запятую (по ритмике фразы, видимо), поэтому, возможно, я и склонен видеть общий член там где его нет. Но без этого "в статье" запятая сама, что называется, ставится.

*Цитирование аналогичных статей не считается заметкой, и оно не нужно.*

Может, фразу лучше перестроить, дабы во грех не вводить?